# Pre-existing arguments when using queries

Tags: query-posts, wp-query, filters, parameter

I am struggling to understand how queries work with get_posts(), query_posts() and WP_Query().
In particular I do not understand what pre-existing selection may exist when using these on a given page template.
From various blogs it seems that the default situation is that query_posts() and WP_Query() apply any pre-existing filters whilst get_posts supresses them.
However the codex says query_posts() ignores other parameters it receives via the URL (such as page number or category.)
Are these filters / parameters the same or something different?
How can I definitively tell what pre-existing selection will exist when I create a query?

Answer (score 1):

[When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: Hey that's fantastic. 
Sorry I missed finding it for myself. 
Many Thanks